# stacksnippets error when reading uploaded directories

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, stack-snippets

What causes

> *"DOMException: A URI supplied to the API was malformed, or the resulting Data URL has exceeded the URL length limitations for Data URLs."*

at `snippet-javascript-console.min.js`?

Minimal, verifiable, complete example to demonstrate the issue

```js
var dropzone = document.querySelector("input[type=file]");

dropzone.ondrop = function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  var item = e.dataTransfer.items[0].webkitGetAsEntry();

  var directoryReader = item.createReader();
    
  directoryReader.readEntries(
    function(entries) {}
  , function(err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  );

}
```

```html
<input type="file" webkitdirectory>
```

To reproduce use Chrome or Chromium browsers and run stacksnippets and drop a directory at `<input type="file">` element. The code does not throw an error at either jsfiddle or plnkr.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is by design.

Chrome is guarding access to the entries behind a same origin check and our sandbox has a unique origin, [as described here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239560/how-is-my-browser-protected-from-xss-in-stack-snippets/240215#240215).  JSFiddle allows same origin requests via `sandbox="allow-same-origin"`, which is why it works there.